# select data from 2 tables using a third as data glue

Tags: sqlite

I need any help getting data from three tables.
This is my setup:

```
TableA with two columns: id, name
TableB with three columns: id_a, id_c1, id_c2
TableC with two columns: id, name
```

I want as result the following table:

```
TableA.name,TableC.name,TableC.name
```

where the TableC.name(s) are expansion of id_c1, id_c2 of TableB.

Any idea?

Very thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the 3 tables like this:

```
select a.name, c1.name, c2.name
from tablea a inner join tableb b
on b.id_a = a.id
inner join tablec c1
on c1.id = b.id_c1 
inner join tablec c2
on c2.id = b.id_c2
```

Maybe instead of inner joins you need left joins, but I can't tell for sure.